# Ansible - format output list from loop (need all results, not only the last one)

Tags: loops, ansible, output

I have a dict with which I'm doing simple arithmetic operations. That is fine, but when I print result I just get the result for the last key-value pair, not for all of them.

Thanks.

```yaml
    - hosts: localhost
      gather_facts: false
    
      vars:
        dict1: [{x: 1, y: 2},{x: 3, y: 4},{x: 5, y: 6}]
    
      tasks:
      - set_fact:
          percentage: "{{ item.x / item.y * 100}}"
        with_items: "{{dict1}}"
```

```
>ok: [localhost] => (item={'x': 1, 'y': 2}) => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "percentage": "50.0"
    },
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "changed": false,
    "item": {
        "x": 1,
        "y": 2
    }
}
>ok: [localhost] => (item={'x': 3, 'y': 4}) => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "percentage": "75.0"
    },
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "changed": false,
    "item": {
        "x": 3,
        "y": 4
    }
}
>ok: [localhost] => (item={'x': 5, 'y': 6}) => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "percentage": "83.33333333333334"
    },
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "changed": false,
    "item": {
        "x": 5,
        "y": 6
    }
}
```

Result when I print it:

```yaml
    debug:
      msg: "{{ percentage }}"
```

It's only the last value:

> ok: [localhost] => {
> "msg": "83.33333333333334"
> }

UPDATE (WITH REGISTER):

```yaml
          - name: Show percentage
            debug:
              msg: "{{ item.x / item.y * 100}}"
            with_items: "{{ dict1 }}"
            register: percentage
        
          - name: Show result
            debug:
              var: percentage # dict
        
          - name: Show result
            debug:
              var: percentage.results # list
```

RESULT (with not only results, but also item, loop and other informational things I don't need):

```
>ok: [localhost] => {
    "percentage.results": [
        {
            "ansible_loop_var": "item",
            "changed": false,
            "failed": false,
            "item": {
                "x": 1,
                "y": 2
            },
            "msg": "50.0"
        },
        {
            "ansible_loop_var": "item",
            "changed": false,
            "failed": false,
            "item": {
                "x": 3,
                "y": 4
            },
            "msg": "75.0"
        },
        {
            "ansible_loop_var": "item",
            "changed": false,
            "failed": false,
            "item": {
                "x": 5,
                "y": 6
            },
            "msg": "83.33333333333334"
        }
    ]
```

}

Comment: Right, "_I just get the result for the last key-value pair, not for all of them._" that is the expected behavior for the shown `set_fact` loop since it is registering every loop run the value new.

Comment: I guess it is. How can I save the whole output? I tried adding register after loop, but when I printed it got only the last result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Jinja to create the list. For example,

```yaml
percentage: |
  [
  {% for i in dict1 %}
  {{ i.x / i.y }},
  {% endfor %}
  ]
```

gives

```yaml
percentage:
  - 0.5
  - 0.75
  - 0.8333333333333334
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    dict1: [{x: 1, y: 2},{x: 3, y: 4},{x: 5, y: 6}]
    percentage: |
      [
      {% for i in dict1 %}
      {{ i.x / i.y }},
      {% endfor %}
      ]

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: percentage|type_debug
    - debug:
        var: percentage
```

Comment: This is a very good example for how to use the syntax from the Jinja2 [Template Designer Documentation](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/) (... and often overseen in Ansible context). It should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Not sure do I need to open new question for this, but if not, if I want to convert Botka's "percentage" list to be a percentage_dict with key:value pairs like "percentage": "real_value", how would I do it?

Comment: Hi Vladimir, I just saw your answer, but just before that have opened a new question, so let be it there, not here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> "*I just get the result for the last key-value pair, not for all of them.*"

That is the expected behavior for the shown `set_fact` loop since it is registering every loop run the value new.

You may let run the following example

```yaml
  - name: Show percentage
    debug:
      msg: "{{ item.x / item.y * 100}}"
    with_items: "{{ dict1 }}"
    register: percentage

  - name: Show result
    debug:
      var: percentage # dict
```

to get familiar with [Registering variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#registering-variables) and the returned data structure for loop.

> *When you register a variable in a task with a loop, the registered variable contains a value for each item in the loop. The data structure placed in the variable during the loop will contain a `results` attribute, that is a list of all responses from the module.*

---

After first test and regarding

> *Yes, but I get all other info that I don't need need i.e. ansible_loop_var': 'item'}, {'ansible_facts' ... or failed': False, 'changed': False, 'item':.. I need just a list with pure results, without that additional info.*

to narrow down you could do further runs with

```yaml
  - name: Show result
    debug:
      var: percentage.results # list
```

resulting into an output of

```yaml
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg:
  - ansible_loop_var: item
    changed: false
    failed: false
    item:
      x: 1
      y: 2
    msg: '50.0'
  - ansible_loop_var: item
    changed: false
    failed: false
    item:
      x: 3
      y: 4
    msg: '75.0'
  - ansible_loop_var: item
    changed: false
    failed: false
    item:
      x: 5
      y: 6
    msg: '83.3333333333'
```

That is one possible approach for creating a result list.

---

**Follow Up**

It seems that you like to have the percentage results only. Therefore it will be necessary to work further on the list to get the values of the `msg` element out.

A very simple approach and which isn't mentioned for further data processing

```yaml
  - name: Show result
    debug:
      msg: "{{ item.msg }}"
    loop: "{{ percentage.results }}"
    loop_control:
      label: "{{ item.item }}"
```

will result into an output of

```yaml
TASK [Show result] ****************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={u'y': 2, u'x': 1}) =>
  msg: '50.0'
ok: [localhost] => (item={u'y': 4, u'x': 3}) =>
  msg: '75.0'
ok: [localhost] => (item={u'y': 6, u'x': 5}) =>
  msg: '83.3333333333'
```

Comment: Yes, but I get all other info that I don't need need i.e. ansible_loop_var': 'item'}, {'ansible_facts' ... or failed': False, 'changed': False, 'item':.. I need just a list with pure results, without that additional info.

Comment: When I add what what you posted I get "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!: 'dict object' has no attribute 'result'". If you thought just percentage.results (without "result" between) it remove one word "result" (or one level) from the output, but I still have all mentioned above (loop_var, item).

Comment: "_If you thought just percentage.results_", good point from the test. I've edited the answer accordingly. Regarding "_I still have all mentioned above (loop_var, item)_" it seems I do not understand where or what is the question.

Comment: I will paste the result I'm getting above